Org-mode code blocks and results side-by-side in beamer export?
I'm using org-mode to generate slides for a class I'm teaching, and one of the things I do is use org-babel to show code snippets, run them and display the results.
However, in the generated Beamer code, the results appear in a list after all of the code. This is a bit awkward if there's multiple lines that are being evaluated.
For example, right now if I have something like this:
  - 
    #+begin_src racket :results list raw :exports both
    (+ 2 3)
    (- 10 0.5)
    (* 1/3 2/3)
    #+end_src

In the generated beamer slide, I get a bullet point with a minted environment of the source code, and then a list of the answers for each line.
Ideally, I want something that looks like this:
    (+ 2 3)       ;; 5
    (- 10 0.5)    ;; 9.5
    (* 1/3 2/3)   ;; 2/9

i.e. I want to be able to have a code block that has multiple expressions, and when I export to pdf, babel runs the expressions, gets the result, and includes them beside the original line.
Is something like this possible? Even if the results were just in a column beside the code block.

Here's the Beamer example from the manual, modified to use a python source block (I don't have racket or ob-racket installed):
#+STARTUP: beamer

#+TITLE: Example Presentation
#+AUTHOR: Carsten Dominik
#+OPTIONS: H:2 toc:t num:t
#+LATEX_CLASS: beamer
#+LATEX_CLASS_OPTIONS: [presentation]
#+BEAMER_THEME: Madrid
#+COLUMNS: %45ITEM %10BEAMER_ENV(Env) %10BEAMER_ACT(Act) %4BEAMER_COL(Col)

* This is the first structural section

** Frame 1
*** Code                                                                                                     :B_block:
    :PROPERTIES:
    :BEAMER_COL: 0.48
    :BEAMER_ENV: block
    :END:

    #+name: code-block-1
    #+begin_src python :results output list raw :exports both
      print(2+3)
      print(10 - 0.5)
      print((1/3) * (2/3))
    #+end_src

*** Results                                                                                                  :B_block:
    :PROPERTIES:
    :BEAMER_COL: 0.48
    :BEAMER_ACT: <2->
    :BEAMER_ENV: block
    :END:

    #+RESULTS: code-block-1
    - 5
    - 9.5
    - 0.2222222222222222


**** This will be formatted as a beamer note                       :B_note:
     :PROPERTIES:
     :BEAMER_env: note
     :END:
** Frame 2 (where we will not use columns)
*** Request
    Please test this stuff!


The main trick is to name the code block and move the named #+RESULTS block to the place shown above on first evaluation. After that, re-evaluation of the code block finds the named #+RESULTS block, even though there is unrelated stuff in-between.
The naming trick is very useful: my recommendation is to name all your code blocks.

Perfect, this is just what I'm looking for! Is there any way to make a shorthand for this so I don't have to type out the PROPERTIES each time?

Read the whole Beamer section in the manuall; in particular, the Editing Support subsection shows a shortcut for part of it. You can also use more general Emacs facilities, like abbrevs  or skeletons. The Emacs manual describes those.

Do C-h i g(emacs) RET i autotyping RET to read about abbrevs and skeletons (or simpler: C-h i g(autotype) - it's a separate manual). Also, if you don't know how to use Info, you should read the Info manual: C-h i g(info).
